# FileAlreadyExistsException occurred when I was exporting data from Presto with Hive engine on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, presto

I tried to export data from the S3 bucket to other S3 bucket using Presto with Hive engine on Amazon EMR, like ETL, but FileAlreadyExistsException occurred when I was exporting data.
How can I export data using Presto?

### Environments

- emr-4.3.0
- Hive 1.0.0
- Presto-Sandbox 0.130

### Error

I tried the following operation:

```
$ hive
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE logs(log string)
   -> LOCATION 's3://foo-bucket/logs/';

hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3_export(log string)
   -> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   -> LOCATION 's3://foo-bucket/export/';

hive> exit;

$ presto-cli --catalog hive --schema default
presto:default> INSERT INTO s3_export SELECT log FROM logs;
Query 20160203_125741_00018_ba5sw, FAILED, 3 nodes
Splits: 7 total, 1 done (14.29%)
0:01 [39 rows, 4KB] [49 rows/s, 5.13KB/s]

Query 20160203_125741_00018_ba5sw failed: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by Presto Hive connector does not like the symlink `/tmp/` EMR (4.2 and 4.3) is using for `hive.s3.staging-directory`, you can use the Configuration API to overwrite `hive.s3.staging-directory` and set it to `/mnt/tmp/`, like this:

```
classification=presto-connector-hive,properties=[hive.s3.staging-directory=/mnt/tmp/]
```

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the problem by the following command:

```
presto-cli --catalog hive --schema default --execute 'select log from logs' | aws s3 cp - s3://foo-bucket/export/data.txt
```